# rxjava: Can I use retry() but with delay?

Tags: java, rx-java

I am using rxjava in my Android app to handle network requests asynchronously. Now I would like to retry a failed network request only after a certain time has passed.

Is there any way to use retry() on an Observable but to retry only after a certain delay?

Is there a way to let the Observable know that is is currently being retried (as opposed to tried for the first time)?

I had a look at debounce()/throttleWithTimeout() but they seem to be doing something different.

**Edit:**

I think I found one way to do it, but I'd be interested in either confirmation that this is the correct way to do it or for other, better ways.

What I am doing is this: In the call() method of my Observable.OnSubscribe, before I call the Subscribers onError() method, I simply let the Thread sleep for the desired amount of time. So, to retry every 1000 milliseconds, I do something like this:

```
@Override
public void call(Subscriber<? super List<ProductNode>> subscriber) {
    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "trying to load all products with pid: " + pid);
        subscriber.onNext(productClient.getProductNodesForParentId(pid));
        subscriber.onCompleted();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        subscriber.onError(e);
    }
}
```

Since this method is running on an IO thread anyway it does not block the UI. The only problem I can see is that even the first error is reported with delay so the delay is there even if there's no retry(). I'd like it better if the delay wasn't applied *after* an error but instead *before* a retry (but not before the first try, obviously).

Answer (score 184, accepted):

You can use the `retryWhen()` operator to add retry logic to any Observable.

The following class contains the retry logic:

#### RxJava 2.x

```java
public class RetryWithDelay implements Function<Observable<? extends Throwable>, Observable<?>> {
    private final int maxRetries;
    private final int retryDelayMillis;
    private int retryCount;

    public RetryWithDelay(final int maxRetries, final int retryDelayMillis) {
        this.maxRetries = maxRetries;
        this.retryDelayMillis = retryDelayMillis;
        this.retryCount = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<?> apply(final Observable<? extends Throwable> attempts) {
        return attempts
                .flatMap(new Function<Throwable, Observable<?>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<?> apply(final Throwable throwable) {
                        if (++retryCount < maxRetries) {
                            // When this Observable calls onNext, the original
                            // Observable will be retried (i.e. re-subscribed).
                            return Observable.timer(retryDelayMillis,
                                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                        }

                        // Max retries hit. Just pass the error along.
                        return Observable.error(throwable);
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

#### RxJava 1.x

```java
public class RetryWithDelay implements
        Func1<Observable<? extends Throwable>, Observable<?>> {

    private final int maxRetries;
    private final int retryDelayMillis;
    private int retryCount;

    public RetryWithDelay(final int maxRetries, final int retryDelayMillis) {
        this.maxRetries = maxRetries;
        this.retryDelayMillis = retryDelayMillis;
        this.retryCount = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<?> call(Observable<? extends Throwable> attempts) {
        return attempts
                .flatMap(new Func1<Throwable, Observable<?>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<?> call(Throwable throwable) {
                        if (++retryCount < maxRetries) {
                            // When this Observable calls onNext, the original
                            // Observable will be retried (i.e. re-subscribed).
                            return Observable.timer(retryDelayMillis,
                                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                        }

                        // Max retries hit. Just pass the error along.
                        return Observable.error(throwable);
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Usage:

```java
// Add retry logic to existing observable.
// Retry max of 3 times with a delay of 2 seconds.
observable
    .retryWhen(new RetryWithDelay(3, 2000));
```

Comment: That's great to know - thank you very much!
The question now is: Do I accept your answer as the correct one or do I keep Alexis Contour's answer because it was the correct one when I asked the question...

Comment: `Error:(73, 20) error: incompatible types: RetryWithDelay cannot be converted to Func1<? super Observable<? extends Throwable>,? extends Observable<?>>`

Comment: @nima I had the same problem, change `RetryWithDelay` to this: http://pastebin.com/6SiZeKnC

Comment: Looks like the RxJava retryWhen operator has changed since I originally wrote this. I'll get the answer updated.

Comment: Also, `retryDelayMillis` should be of type long, since that's what `Observable.timer()` takes as a first parameter.

Comment: You should update this answer to comply with RxJava 2

Comment: how would the rxjava 2 version look for kotlin?

Comment: Implementation which is **not specifically** to `Observable` can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/Jj1kWHKa) (supports all RxJava 2.x compatible observables, based on `Publisher` interface).

Comment: @kjones can you help with this rxjava issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61352701/passing-list-to-rxjava-concat-and-when-remove-item-in-onnext-or-onerror-causes-c?noredirect=1#comment108536141_61352701

Answer (score 24):

Inspired by [Paul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38431584/1192811), and if you are not concerned with `retryWhen` problems stated by [Abhijit Sarkar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38429101/1192811), the simplest way to delay resubscription with rxJava2 unconditionnaly is :

```
source.retryWhen(throwables -> throwables.delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
```

You may want to see more samples and explanations on [retryWhen and repeatWhen](http://blog.danlew.net/2016/01/25/rxjavas-repeatwhen-and-retrywhen-explained/).

Answer (score 19):

This example works with jxjava 2.2.2:

Retry without delay:

```java
Single.just(somePaylodData)
   .map(data -> someConnection.send(data))
   .retry(5)
   .doOnSuccess(status -> log.info("Yay! {}", status);
```

Retry with delay:

```java
Single.just(somePaylodData)
   .map(data -> someConnection.send(data))
   .retryWhen((Flowable<Throwable> f) -> f.take(5).delay(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
   .doOnSuccess(status -> log.info("Yay! {}", status)
   .doOnError((Throwable error) 
                -> log.error("I tried five times with a 300ms break" 
                             + " delay in between. But it was in vain."));
```

Our source single fails if someConnection.send() fails.
When that happens, the observable of failures inside retryWhen emits the error.
We delay that emission by 300ms and send it back to signal a retry.
take(5) guarantees that our signaling observable will terminate after we receive five errors.
retryWhen sees the termination and doesn't retry after the fifth failure.

Comment: This approach seems straightforward, but it swallows the error when retries run out instead of throwing it. For some situations it might come handy, though.

Answer (score 9):

This is a solution based on Ben Christensen's snippets I saw, [RetryWhen Example](http://bl.ocks.org/benjchristensen/3363d420607f03307dd0), and [RetryWhenTestsConditional](http://bl.ocks.org/benjchristensen/fde2e7d2dad2c746a449) (I had to change `n.getThrowable()` to `n` for it to work). I used [evant/gradle-retrolambda](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda) to make the lambda notation work on Android, but you don't have to use lambdas (although it's highly recommended). For the delay I implemented exponential back-off, but you can plug in what ever backoff logic you want there. For completeness I added the `subscribeOn` and `observeOn` operators. I'm using [ReactiveX/RxAndroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid) for the `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()`.

```
int ATTEMPT_COUNT = 10;

public class Tuple<X, Y> {
    public final X x;
    public final Y y;

    public Tuple(X x, Y y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}


observable
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .retryWhen(
            attempts -> {
                return attempts.zipWith(Observable.range(1, ATTEMPT_COUNT + 1), (n, i) -> new Tuple<Throwable, Integer>(n, i))
                .flatMap(
                        ni -> {
                            if (ni.y > ATTEMPT_COUNT)
                                return Observable.error(ni.x);
                            return Observable.timer((long) Math.pow(2, ni.y), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                        });
            })
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(subscriber);
```

Comment: this looks elegant but I'm not using lamba functions, how can I write without lambas? @amitai-hoze

Comment: also how do I write it such that I can reused this retry function for other `Observable` objects?

Comment: nevermind, I've used `kjones` solution and it's working out perfect for me, thanks

Answer (score 8):

instead of using MyRequestObservable.retry I use a wrapper function retryObservable(MyRequestObservable, retrycount, seconds) which return a new Observable that handle the indirection for the delay so I can do

```java
retryObservable(restApi.getObservableStuff(), 3, 30)
    .subscribe(new Action1<BonusIndividualList>(){
        @Override
        public void call(BonusIndividualList arg0) 
        {
            //success!
        }
    }, 
    new Action1<Throwable>(){
        @Override
        public void call(Throwable arg0) { 
           // failed after the 3 retries !
        }}); 


// wrapper code
private static <T> Observable<T> retryObservable(
        final Observable<T> requestObservable, final int nbRetry,
        final long seconds) {

    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<T>() {

        @Override
        public void call(final Subscriber<? super T> subscriber) {
            requestObservable.subscribe(new Action1<T>() {

                @Override
                public void call(T arg0) {
                    subscriber.onNext(arg0);
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                }
            },

            new Action1<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Throwable error) {

                    if (nbRetry > 0) {
                        Observable.just(requestObservable)
                                .delay(seconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                .observeOn(mainThread())
                                .subscribe(new Action1<Observable<T>>(){
                                    @Override
                                    public void call(Observable<T> observable){
                                        retryObservable(observable,
                                                nbRetry - 1, seconds)
                                                .subscribe(subscriber);
                                    }
                                });
                    } else {
                        // still fail after retries
                        subscriber.onError(error);
                    }

                }
            });

        }

    });

}
```

Comment: I am terribly sorry for not responding earlier - somehow I missed the notification from SO that there was a reply to my question... I upvoted your respone because I like the idea, but I am not sure whether - according to the principles of SO - I should accept the answer as it is more of a workaround than a direct answer. But I guess, since you are giving a workaround the answer to my initial question is "no, you can't"...

Answer (score 8):

Based on [kjones](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25292833/2146871) answer here is Kotlin version of RxJava 2.x retry with a delay as an extension. Replace `Observable` to create the same extension for `Flowable`.

```
fun <T> Observable<T>.retryWithDelay(maxRetries: Int, retryDelayMillis: Int): Observable<T> {
    var retryCount = 0

    return retryWhen { thObservable ->
        thObservable.flatMap { throwable ->
            if (++retryCount < maxRetries) {
                Observable.timer(retryDelayMillis.toLong(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            } else {
                Observable.error(throwable)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then just use it on observable `observable.retryWithDelay(3, 1000)`

Comment: Is it possible to replace this with `Single` as well?

Comment: @Papps Yeah that should work, just note that `flatMap` there will have to use `Flowable.timer` and `Flowable.error ` even though the function is `Single<T>.retryWithDelay`.

Answer (score 7):

`retryWhen` is a complicated, perhaps even buggy, operator. The official doc and at least one answer here use `range` operator, which will fail if there are no retries to be made. See my [discussion](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/4207) with ReactiveX member David Karnok.

I improved upon kjones' answer by changing `flatMap` to `concatMap` and by adding a `RetryDelayStrategy` class. `flatMap` doesn't preserve order of emission while `concatMap` does, which is important for delays with back-off. The `RetryDelayStrategy`, as the name indicates, let's the user choose from various modes of generating retry delays, including back-off.
The code is available on my [GitHub](https://github.com/asarkar/java/blob/master/concurrency-learning/src/main/java/org/abhijitsarkar/rx/ChuckNorrisJokesService.java) complete with the following test cases:

1. Succeeds on 1st attempt (no retries)
2. Fails after 1 retry
3. Attempts to retry 3 times but succeeds on 2nd hence doesn't retry 3rd time
4. Succeeds on 3rd retry

See `setRandomJokes` method.

Answer (score 5):

Same answer as from ***kjones*** but updated to latest version
For **RxJava 2.x** version: *('io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.3')*

```
public class RetryWithDelay implements Function<Flowable<Throwable>, Publisher<?>> {

    private final int maxRetries;
    private final long retryDelayMillis;
    private int retryCount;

    public RetryWithDelay(final int maxRetries, final int retryDelayMillis) {
        this.maxRetries = maxRetries;
        this.retryDelayMillis = retryDelayMillis;
        this.retryCount = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Publisher<?> apply(Flowable<Throwable> throwableFlowable) throws Exception {
        return throwableFlowable.flatMap(new Function<Throwable, Publisher<?>>() {
            @Override
            public Publisher<?> apply(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                if (++retryCount < maxRetries) {
                    // When this Observable calls onNext, the original
                    // Observable will be retried (i.e. re-subscribed).
                    return Flowable.timer(retryDelayMillis,
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                }

                // Max retries hit. Just pass the error along.
                return Flowable.error(throwable);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Usage:

// Add retry logic to existing observable.
// Retry max of 3 times with a delay of 2 seconds.

```
observable
    .retryWhen(new RetryWithDelay(3, 2000));
```

Answer (score 3):

Now with RxJava version 1.0+ you can use zipWith to achieve retry with delay.

Adding modifications to [kjones](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25292833/4387543) answer.

**Modified**

```
public class RetryWithDelay implements 
                            Func1<Observable<? extends Throwable>, Observable<?>> {

    private final int MAX_RETRIES;
    private final int DELAY_DURATION;
    private final int START_RETRY;

    /**
     * Provide number of retries and seconds to be delayed between retry.
     *
     * @param maxRetries             Number of retries.
     * @param delayDurationInSeconds Seconds to be delays in each retry.
     */
    public RetryWithDelay(int maxRetries, int delayDurationInSeconds) {
        MAX_RETRIES = maxRetries;
        DELAY_DURATION = delayDurationInSeconds;
        START_RETRY = 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<?> call(Observable<? extends Throwable> observable) {
        return observable
                .delay(DELAY_DURATION, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .zipWith(Observable.range(START_RETRY, MAX_RETRIES), 
                         new Func2<Throwable, Integer, Integer>() {
                             @Override
                             public Integer call(Throwable throwable, Integer attempt) {
                                  return attempt;
                             }
                         });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a delay in the Observable returned in the retryWhen Operator

```
          /**
 * Here we can see how onErrorResumeNext works and emit an item in case that an error occur in the pipeline and an exception is propagated
 */
@Test
public void observableOnErrorResumeNext() {
    Subscription subscription = Observable.just(null)
                                          .map(Object::toString)
                                          .doOnError(failure -> System.out.println("Error:" + failure.getCause()))
                                          .retryWhen(errors -> errors.doOnNext(o -> count++)
                                                                     .flatMap(t -> count > 3 ? Observable.error(t) : Observable.just(null).delay(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)),
                                                     Schedulers.newThread())
                                          .onErrorResumeNext(t -> {
                                              System.out.println("Error after all retries:" + t.getCause());
                                              return Observable.just("I save the world for extinction!");
                                          })
                                          .subscribe(s -> System.out.println(s));
    new TestSubscriber((Observer) subscription).awaitTerminalEvent(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

You can see more examples here. https://github.com/politrons/reactive

Answer (score 1):

in the event when you need to print out the retry count,
you can use the example provided in Rxjava's wiki page https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators

```
observable.retryWhen(errors ->
    // Count and increment the number of errors.
    errors.map(error -> 1).scan((i, j) -> i + j)  
       .doOnNext(errorCount -> System.out.println(" -> query errors #: " + errorCount))
       // Limit the maximum number of retries.
       .takeWhile(errorCount -> errorCount < retryCounts)   
       // Signal resubscribe event after some delay.
       .flatMapSingle(errorCount -> Single.timer(errorCount, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
```

Answer (score 1):

Worked from me with

```
//retry with retryCount time after 1 sec of delay
observable.retryWhen(throwableFlowable -> {
                return throwableFlowable.take(retryCount).delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do it like this:

```
                  Observable.just("")
                            .delay(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS) //delay
                            .flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<File>>() {
                                @Override
                                public Observable<File> call(String s) {
                                    L.from(TAG).d("postAvatar=");

                                    File file = PhotoPickUtil.getTempFile();
                                    if (file.length() <= 0) {
                                        throw new NullPointerException();
                                    }
                                    return Observable.just(file);
                                }
                            })
                            .retry(6)
                            .subscribe(new Action1<File>() {
                                @Override
                                public void call(File file) {
                                    postAvatar(file);
                                }
                            }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
                                @Override
                                public void call(Throwable throwable) {

                                }
                            });
```

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin & RxJava1 version

```
class RetryWithDelay(private val MAX_RETRIES: Int, private val DELAY_DURATION_IN_SECONDS: Long)
    : Function1<Observable<out Throwable>, Observable<*>> {

    private val START_RETRY: Int = 1

    override fun invoke(observable: Observable<out Throwable>): Observable<*> {
        return observable.delay(DELAY_DURATION_IN_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .zipWith(Observable.range(START_RETRY, MAX_RETRIES),
                object : Function2<Throwable, Int, Int> {
                    override fun invoke(throwable: Throwable, attempt: Int): Int {
                        return attempt
                    }
                })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Kotlin) I little bit improved code with exponential backoff and applied defense emitting of Observable.range():

```
    fun testOnRetryWithDelayExponentialBackoff() {
    val interval = 1
    val maxCount = 3
    val ai = AtomicInteger(1);
    val source = Observable.create<Unit> { emitter ->
        val attempt = ai.getAndIncrement()
        println("Subscribe ${attempt}")
        if (attempt >= maxCount) {
            emitter.onNext(Unit)
            emitter.onComplete()
        }
        emitter.onError(RuntimeException("Test $attempt"))
    }

    // Below implementation of "retryWhen" function, remove all "println()" for real code.
    val sourceWithRetry: Observable<Unit> = source.retryWhen { throwableRx ->
        throwableRx.doOnNext({ println("Error: $it") })
                .zipWith(Observable.range(1, maxCount)
                        .concatMap { Observable.just(it).delay(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) },
                        BiFunction { t1: Throwable, t2: Int -> t1 to t2 }
                )
                .flatMap { pair ->
                    if (pair.second >= maxCount) {
                        Observable.error(pair.first)
                    } else {
                        val delay = interval * 2F.pow(pair.second)
                        println("retry delay: $delay")
                        Observable.timer(delay.toLong(), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    }
                }
    }

    //Code to print the result in terminal.
    sourceWithRetry
            .doOnComplete { println("Complete") }
            .doOnError({ println("Final Error: $it") })
            .blockingForEach { println("$it") }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use retryWhen

```
     /**
     * Retry Handler Support
     * @param errors
     * @param predicate filter error 
     * @param maxTry
     * @param periodStrategy
     * @param timeUnit
     * @return 
     */
    private  Flowable<?> retrySupport(Flowable<Throwable> errors, Predicate<? super Throwable> predicate , Integer maxTry , Function<Long, Long> periodStrategy , TimeUnit timeUnit )
    {
        LongAdder errorCount = new LongAdder();
        return errors
                .doOnNext(e -> {
                    errorCount.increment();
                    long currentCount = errorCount.longValue();
                    boolean tryContinue = predicate.test(e) && currentCount < maxTry;
                    Logger.i("No. of errors: %d , %s",  currentCount,
                            tryContinue ? String.format("please wait %d %s.", periodStrategy.apply(currentCount), timeUnit.name()) : "skip and throw");
                    if(!tryContinue)
                        throw  e;
                } )
                .flatMapSingle(e -> Single.timer( periodStrategy.apply(errorCount.longValue()), timeUnit));
    }
```

Sample

```
    private Single<DeviceInfo> getErrorToken( String device)
    {
        return Single.error(  new IOException( "network is disconnect!" ) );
    }

//only retry when emit IOExpcetion
//delay 1s,2s,4s,8s,16s

this.getErrorToken( this.deviceCode )
     .retryWhen( error -> retrySupport( error, 
                 e-> e instanceof IOException,
                 5 , 
                 count-> (long)Math.pow(2,count-1),TimeUnit.SECONDS ) )
     .subscribe( deviceInfo1 -> Logger.i( "----Get Device Info---" ) ,
                 e -> Logger.e( e, "On Error" ) ,
                 () -> Logger.i("<<<<<no more>>>>>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit too late for this one, but just in case this could still be useful for someone, I created a Kotlin extension function for RxJava 2 that will retry with an exponential backoff strategy:

```
  private fun <T> Observable<T>.retryWithExponentialBackoff(): Observable<T> {
    val retriesSubject = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(0)
    return doOnNext { retriesSubject.onNext(0) }
        .retryWhen {
          it.withLatestFrom(retriesSubject) { _, retryCount ->
            retriesSubject.onNext(retryCount + 1)
            retryCount
          }.flatMap { retryCount ->
            when (retryCount) {
              MAX_RETRY_COUNT -> Observable.error(RuntimeException("Max number of retries reached"))
              else -> Observable.timer(2.0.pow(retryCount).toLong(), SECONDS)
            }
          }
        }
  }
```