# Correct way to retry with delay on Couchbase getAndLock if lock was already held?

Tags: java, couchbase, reactive-programming, rx-java

I am using the new Couchbase Java Client API 2.1.1 and therefore JavaRx to access my Couchbase cluster.
When using asynchronous `getAndLock` on an already locked document, getAndLock fails with a `TemporaryLockFailureException`. In another SO question ([rxjava: Can I use retry() but with delay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22066481/rxjava-can-i-use-retry-but-with-delay?rq=1)) I found out how to retry with delay.

Here is my adopted code:

```
    CountDownLatchWithResultData<JsonDocument> resultCdl = new CountDownLatchWithResultData<>(1);

    couchbaseBucket.async().getAndLock(key, LOCK_TIME).retryWhen((errorObserver) -> {
        return errorObserver.flatMap((Throwable t) -> {
            if (t instanceof TemporaryLockFailureException) {
                return Observable.timer(RETRY_DELAY_MS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            }
            return Observable.error(t);
        });
    }).subscribe(new Subscriber<JsonDocument>() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            resultCdl.countDown();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            resultCdl.countDown();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(JsonDocument t) {
            resultCdl.setInformation(t);
        }

    });

    ........

    resultCdl.await();

    if (resultCdl.getInformation() == null) {
        //do stuff
    } else ....
```

(`CountDownLatchWithResultData` simply extends a normal `CountDownLatch` and adds two methods to store some information before the count has reached 0 and retrieve it afterwards)

So basically I'd like this code to

- try to get the lock infinitely once every `RETRY_DELAY_MS` milliseconds if a `TemporaryLockFailureException` occured and then call `onNext`
- or to fail completely on other exceptions
- or to directly call `onNext` if there is no exception at all

The problem now is that when retrying, it only retries once and the JsonDocument from `resultCdl.getInformation()` is always null in this case even though the document exists. It seems `onNext` is never called.
If there is no exception, the code works fine.
So apparently I am doing something wrong here but I have no clue as to where the problem might be. Does returning `Observable.timer` imply that with this new Obervable also the previously associated `retryWhen` is executed again? Is it the `CountDownLatch` with count 1 getting in the way?

Comment: I try to simulate your issue without couchbase, and only with plain Observable which emits value or errors. I didn't reproduce it. Have you put a breakpoint into onNext() to check if it's called ?

Answer (score 0):

This one is subtle. Up to version 2.2.0, the `Observable`s from the SDK are in the "hot" category. In effect that means that even if no subscription is made, they start emitting. They will also emit the same data to every newcoming `Subscriber`, so in effect they cache the data.

So what you retry does is resubscribe to an `Observable` that will always emit the same thing (in this case an error). I suspect it comes out of the retry loop just because the lock maximum duration is `LOCK_TIME`...

Try wrapping the call to `asyncBucket.getAndLock` inside an `Observable.defer` (or migrate to the 2.2.x SDK if that's something you could do, see [release and migration notes starting from 2.2.0](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.1/sdks/java-2.2/release-notes.html#story-h2-10)).