# How to queue API calls when you're offline while using Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I'm using Retrofit in combination with rx-java and have the following question:

Is there a way to queue API calls to a server when the device is offline so that they can be fired when the device is back online again.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**EDIT: March 2021** you should now use [Work Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager) instead.

---

You need to add queue to your project in the first place and pipe Retrofit jobs thru that queue. So either create own queue or check if libraries like [android-priority-jobqueue](https://github.com/yigit/android-priority-jobqueue/) fit your requirements (that one also handles persistency of  queued jobs, so app kill/reboot is less painful)

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to save the queue to a persistence storage for when the app is restarted?

Comment: Sure. Actually  android-priority-jobqueue  does it out of the box (in fact it stores it first, then processes). With custom implementation you have to do that yourself

Comment: Wow that sounds amazing! I'll dive into it! Thanks!

Comment: I've implemented the lib in my code and I have to say that I'm really amazed! This is by far the best approach I could imaging. Many thanks for pointing me into the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

I think Marcin Orlowski's answer was good. But if you want to go with rxjava, you can use `.retry()` with check, are you online, inside of it.

[rxjava: Can I use retry() but with delay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22066481/rxjava-can-i-use-retry-but-with-delay)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The calls should also be cached and sent when the app is restarted after a day or so. The retry function in only when the app is in memory right?