# Mysterious issue with okhttp call (SocketTimeException)

Tags: retrofit, rx-java, okhttp, retrofit2

I am using Okhttp 2.5, 2.6, 2.7 with RxJava and Retrofit 2. I got some mysterious issue with okhttp call. When I made call with retrofit my Okhttp interceptor get called immediately while NetworkInterceptor called after 4 to 5 second. Sometime its more than 15 second, and leads SocketTimeoutExcpetion.

Please suggest, What should I do to solve this problem. Is there any thread blocking my call get executed?

Comment: I am getting stuck due to this behaviour of okhttp... it there any way to figure it out.

Comment: Is your issue resolved

Answer (score 0):

OkHttp is behaving as it should. A [`SocketTimeoutException`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15608499/5623874) happens when the server takes longer to respond than what the client is willing to wait, and it just gives up. There is a default read timeout of 10 seconds since OkHttp [2.5](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/okhttp_25/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient.java#L191) (and including the new 3.0), which would explain why you're getting the exception after 15 seconds.

You can **set your own timeouts** to allow your server ample time to respond:

```java
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client.setConnectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  // connect timeout
client.setReadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);     // socket timeout
```

Note that this doesn't *handle* the exception, it will still be thrown if the client doesn't receive a response in `x` seconds now. I would make sure to actually catch the exception. This would be an appropriate place to have your retry logic.

---

Since you're using RxJava with Retrofit, you could just add [`retry/retryWhen`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/retry.html) to your chain to catch and handle `SocketTimeoutException` errors, and maybe even mix in [exponential backoff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25292833/5623874).

Comment: Roth, thanks for reply. I am using your mentioned configuration, also retryWhen. But, problem is my network connection and server is stable and I am getting sockettimeout. I also searched regarding this, some post suggest its ipv6 problem, but our server is ipv4. So, I am not sure what kind of problem is this. Did you ever face such kind of problem? My users also facing the same.

Answer (score 0):

I know that is an old story but I seems to found a solution.
To fix **SocketTimeoutException** you need to setup connection pool with 0 (!) idle connections!

```
okBuilder.connectionPool(new ConnectionPool(0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
```