# Using takeUntil and debounce for recursive call

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have to implement a function that call a service until the status of the returned body is `depositDone` or `faulted`. If the status is not one of those, i have to call again the service, with a delay of 500 milliseconds from the last one.

It's the first time i'm using RxJava and i don't know if I am doing it correctly, since i can not test it at the moment.

```
private void startPollingPaymentStatus() {

        Observable<CimaPaymentStatusResponse> response = request.getPaymentStatus();

        response.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .map(result -> result.paymentStatus)
                .takeUntil(responseState -> (responseState == CimaPaymentEnum.depositDone || responseState == CimaPaymentEnum.faulted))
                .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .subscribe(this::onPaymentPollingUpdate, this::handleCimaError);
    }

    private void onPaymentPollingUpdate(CimaPaymentEnum cimaPaymentEnum) {
        if (cimaPaymentEnum == CimaPaymentEnum.depositDone || cimaPaymentEnum == CimaPaymentEnum.faulted) {
            //stop polling, operation completed
            onCustomPaymentDone(null, cimaPayment, null);
        } else {
            // Not successful
            CustomAlertDialog customAlertDialog = new CustomAlertDialog(this);
            customAlertDialog.setTitle(R.string.payments_cima);
            customAlertDialog.setMessage(R.string.cima_payment_error);
            customAlertDialog.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok), null);
            customAlertDialog.show();
        }
    }
```

Am I doing right?

Comment: What is the type of 'request'? Is it a retrofit interface?

Comment: @DominikSetniewski yes

Comment: Specifying return type of retrofit interface as `Observable` will create an observable which emits one item (because Http request will be made only once). If you want to retry http request, you should use `retryWhen` operator. Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25292833/12026640